# Mostrar div mientras oculto otros (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, botón, div

Quiero mostrar algunos elementos al hacer `click` en un `botón`, pero quiero que si ya esta mostrando un elemento y doy `click` en otro `botón` oculte el elemento previo y muestre el nuevo.

Hice algo como esto:

```
 $( "#b-compra-venta" ).click(function() {
  $( "#box-compra-venta" ).toggle("show");

  $( "#box-desarrollo" ).hide(400);
  $( "#box-tecnologias" ).hide(400);
});

$( "#b-desarrollo" ).click(function() {
  $( "#box-desarrollo" ).toggle("show");

  $( "#box-compra-venta" ).hide(400);
  $( "#box-tecnologias" ).hide(400);
});

$( "#b-tecnologias" ).click(function() {
  $( "#box-tecnologias" ).toggle("show");

  $( "#box-compra-venta" ).hide(400);
  $( "#box-desarrollo" ).hide(400);
});
```

Funciona pero quiero tener recomendaciones.

Mi html es algo como esto:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button id="b-compra-venta" class="btn btn-default">Compra y Venta</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button id="b-desarrollo" class="btn btn-default">Desarrollo</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button id="b-tecnologias" class="btn btn-default">Tecnologias</button>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="box-compra-venta">Contenido compra venta</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="box-desarrollo">Contenido desarrollo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <<div id="box-tecnologias">Contenido Tecnologia</div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: ¿Quieres mejoras u otra forma de hacerlo?

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez la idea es aprender a como hacerlo de forma correcta, por que mi ejemplo funciona pero yo mismo sabia que no era lo mas conveniente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que buscas es simplificar tu codigo, puedes hacer algo como esto.  Si los selectores son muy genericos, puedes agregar clases mas especificas.

```js
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var div = $( "#box-" + id );
  $('.toggle').not(div, '.row').hide(400);
  div.toggle("show");  
});
```

```css
.toggle {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button id="compra-venta" class="btn btn-default">Compra y Venta</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button id="desarrollo" class="btn btn-default">Desarrollo</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button id="tecnologias" class="btn btn-default">Tecnologias</button>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="box-compra-venta" class="toggle">Contenido compra venta</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="box-desarrollo" class="toggle">Contenido desarrollo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="box-tecnologias" class="toggle">Contenido Tecnologia</div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Todos los "box" comienzan escondidos con un "display:none;" desde css.

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta.

Comment: Orale, ya quedo perfecto en lo que estoy haciendo, muchas gra...

Comment: De nada @Critter236 y bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español.